# GIT not running at substituted user - /bin/git: /bin/git: cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, git

I've just installed git on my CentOS 6 (yum install). And I'd like to clone a repository, but keeping in mind that runing GIT as root user is insecure, I try to do it as admin (whose password I don't remember really). Below is a command flow.

```
[root@angkor public_html]# runuser -l admin 'git'
/bin/git: /bin/git: cannot execute binary file
[root@angkor public_html]# su - admin git
Last login: Tue May 28 11:00:08 UTC 2019 on pts/0
/bin/git: /bin/git: cannot execute binary file
[root@angkor public_html]# git
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]
```

As we can see git starts when I run it as root but some error reported whan I try to run it as admin. Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, unfortunately:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1245780

Use this instead:

```
runuser -l admin -c 'git'
```